# in jquery not able to show a specific div in side a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i am working in asp.net mvc application ,have writen following code in jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $(".field-validation-error").hide();
    $(".select-billing-address-button").click(function () {

        $(".edit-address").hide();

        $("#billing-address-select").val(this.value);

        $(".new-address-next-step-button").click();

       $('html,body').animate({

           scrollTop: $(".new-billing-address").offset().top

       }, 'slow');

    });

    $(".adress-new-submit").click(function () {

        $(".field-validation-error").show();

        $(".new-address-next-step-button").click();

        $('html,body').animate({

            scrollTop: $(".new-billing-address").offset().top

        }, 'slow');

    });
```

$(".field-validation-error").hide(); this code the field validation field

but i want to unhide the field validation field when i click  adress-new-submit

button. using the code $(".field-validation-error").show(); but i am not able

the achive the goal using the above code.can any one help me

my html view is as follows

```
<div class="edit-address">
<div class="inputs">
    <label for="BillingNewAddress_FirstName">First name:</label>
        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="First name is required." id="BillingNewAddress_FirstName" name="BillingNewAddress.FirstName" type="text" value="John">
    <span class="required">*</span>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="BillingNewAddress.FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
<div class="inputs">
    <label for="BillingNewAddress_LastName">Last name:</label>
        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Last name is required." id="BillingNewAddress_LastName" name="BillingNewAddress.LastName" type="text" value="Smith">
    <span class="required">*</span>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="BillingNewAddress.LastName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

</div>
<div class="inputs">
    <label for="BillingNewAddress_Email">Email:</label>
        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-email="Wrong email" data-val-required="Email is required." id="BillingNewAddress_Email" name="BillingNewAddress.Email" type="text" value="rakshiraik@gmail.com">
    <span class="required">*</span>
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="BillingNewAddress.Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
    <div class="inputs">
        <label for="BillingNewAddress_Company">Company:</label>
            <input class="text-box single-line" id="BillingNewAddress_Company" name="BillingNewAddress.Company" type="text" value="">
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="BillingNewAddress.Company" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
        <div class="inputs">
        <label for="BillingNewAddress_CountryId">Country:</label>

        <span class="required">*</span>
        <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="BillingNewAddress.CountryId" data-valmsg-replace="true" style="display: none;">Country is required.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="inputs">
        <label for="BillingNewAddress_StateProvinceId">State / province:</label>                
        <span id="states-loading-progress" style="display: none;" class="please-wait"></span>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="BillingNewAddress.StateProvinceId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>


<input id="Location" name="Location" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="off" style="width:400px;"><br><br>

    <div class="inputs">
        <label for="BillingNewAddress_City">City:</label>

    </div>
        <div class="inputs">
        <label for="BillingNewAddress_Address1">Address 1:</label>

   <span class="required">*</span>      
    </div>
        <div class="inputs">
        <label for="BillingNewAddress_Address2">Address 2:</label>
            <input class="text-box single-line" id="BillingNewAddress_Address2" name="BillingNewAddress.Address2" type="text" value="">
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="BillingNewAddress.Address2" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
        <div class="inputs">

    </div>
        <div class="inputs">
        <label for="BillingNewAddress_PhoneNumber">Phone number:</label>

    </div>
        <div class="inputs">

            <input class="text-box single-line" id="BillingNewAddress_FaxNumber" name="BillingNewAddress.FaxNumber" type="text" value="">
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="BillingNewAddress.FaxNumber" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>

<button type="button" title="Continue" class="button-1 adress-new-submit">Continue</button>
```

Comment: can you share html?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: i have updated the html

Answer (score 0):

You can try .toggle() in place of .show()

```js
$(".field-validation-error").toggle();
```

Some times using the ID works, in place of  $(".field-validation-error").toggle(); use "#idName" after giving it an id.
Make sure you try everything.

Comment: "Some times using the ID works" What are you talking about?

Comment: This does not change anything with toggle from the OP case. The ID situation will in fact work if there is a typo in the classname, which in this case there seems to be.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Best of luck solving the problem without the HTML/razor views

Comment: @RohitGupta What are you talking about, I never said anything that i could or would solve it without the html. I just asked what you base "Sometimes using the id works" on.?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I just meant, using ID is sometimes a better option while dealing with such problems.

Comment: @RohitGupta I don't agree since it should not make any difference if you select an element by either id or class. And is don't seem to be anything to do with the question to us Id.